# Fetching the lineitem field from item table when adding the item as lineitem in SO - Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am Learning netsuite,

I am trying to fetch the Customfield "**custitem_celigo_sfnc_salesforce_id**" from item, on sales order module when adding that item in SO line items

here is my sample

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 */
define(['N/record', 'N/search', 'N/url', 'N/https', 'N/runtime'], function(record, search, url, https, runtime) {

    function fieldChanged(context) {
    
        var currentRecord = context.currentRecord;
      
     
            var sublistName = context.sublistId;
            var sublistFieldName = context.fieldId;
            var line = context.line;
            var SFID = context.custitem_celigo_sfnc_salesforce_id;
      
          var descriptionValue = currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({
                            sublistId: sublistName,
                            fieldId: "custitem_celigo_sfnc_salesforce_id"
                        })
      
              alert(JSON.stringify(currentRecord));
              alert(JSON.stringify(test));
          

            return true;
    }
    var exports = {};


    exports.fieldChanged = fieldChanged;

    return exports;
});
```

It is not fetching the custom field , what is the way to do that.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
var descriptionValue = currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: item,
                          fieldId: "custitem_celigo_sfnc_salesforce_id",
                          line:line
                       })
```